# Help interpreting TIP127 datasheet

Tags: transistors, current, darlington

I'm trying to build a constant current 2A amplifier using a TIP 127. To be honest, I have a lack of transistor knowledge.

I decided to analyze a few existent circuits with a TIP127 and the [datasheet](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/TI/TIP125.pdf).

1. One of circuits mentions a voltage drop of 1.2 v between Emitter–Base, Is this a common sense value (2 transistors x 0.6 v drop) or this is an exact value variable per transistor? I'm looking in the datasheet and I cannot find the Emitter Base voltage drop.
2. A resistor between a Vin and the emitter with a specific voltage applied in the base will regulated the current passed to the collector? Is my interpretation correct or there is another away of explaining? I'll provide more details on point 3.
3. For a 2 Amp constant current on the collector:

   - VIn = 12
   - R1=0.3 ohm
   - VBase = 10.2 v
   - EB voltage drop (point 1) is 1.2 v
   - I R1 = (12-10.2-1.2)/0.3 = 2A

Is this correct?

I'm not feeling confident due to lack of knowledge interpreting the datasheet.

Can someone provide a theoretical/educational explanation?

Comment: 1) The parameter you're looking for is: *VBE(on) Base-Emitter On Voltage*. The datasheet says it could be as high as -2.5 V.

Comment: @m.Alin, thanks for the feedback: if the 2.5V is the max, what will be a tipical value, 1.2V (point 1) to 2.5V makes a big difference in current calculation, is the tipical value calculated using trial error values ?

Comment: For a more exact value, take a look at the graph in the datasheet, page 3, figure 2. It shows you the relation between the base-emitter saturation voltage and the collector current. For 2 A collector current it looks like it should have a -1.75 V VBE.

Comment: @RJR: bad English too... bases or basics. Just because i can search on the internet does not make me a proficient ;) Honesty is always the best option.

Comment: RJR's comment is about the (probably unintentional) joke: you state that you lack base knowledge, but it can be read as if you lack the base connection (one of the 3 leads) of a transistor.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon - I assume you meant 24 Watts = 2A x 12V.

Comment: How accurately do you need to set the 2A current? This circuit is NOT a good constant current source due to the potential (groan) for variations in a number of parameters to influence the results. If you are happy with something like a range of between say 1.5A to 2.5A this circuit MAY suffice. If you need eg 2A +/- 100 mA then there are better circuits to use.| Note that at 12V and 2A you will ALWAYS dissipate 24 Watts = 2 A x 12 V. This will be dissipated mainly in the load + in the TIP127. For small resistance loads most power will be in the TIP127 and you will need substantial heatsinking.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Thanks - yes. Could not edit so have reposted in better form.

Comment: @Russel: I want to build a NiMh Fast Charger, monitored via atmel. I have some requirements: stable current at 1.9-2.0A, low heat dissipation, low voltage drop (12v to feed a 6x NiMh cell),  the circuit is to be inside a Toy (Plastics). Can you recommend some alternatives ?

Comment: @Pedro - You MAY find that using a charger IC is an easier path - depends on whether you want to make 1 or many. If you want a well controlled and accurate current source the usual approach is to have a sense resistor in series with the load (= R1 = 0.3 Ohms here), control the load current with a transistor as here (a MOSFET is usually easier than a bipolar, ) and then to use use an opamp to drive the transistor so that the voltage across the sense resistor  tracks a reference voltage. Change Vref and you change Iout. In WRB's diagram the 10.2V and Vbe of A1 approximate what the opamp does.

Comment: NimH charging is not too hard if you have a steady energy source )(eg AC mains). For solar sourced energy that may vary rapidly the 3 main ways of testing NimH for fully charged have issues. | With 12V available you can charge with all cells in series but may have balance issues - one or two cells with low capacity can cause problems if you discharge the battery until one or more but not all cells is at or below V_min_cell_allowed.

Comment: @Russell, yes i don't want mainstream the circuit. I found a charger IC Max712 and it seems much more simple to apply. The main reason why i was looking for simple circuit with an avr, is to monitor the battery progress level, temperature and send periodical info to a station, to provide an estimation when the bot will be ready. Using a Max712 i'm not aware of a method to query the current battery level, the only output is  charge method (fast vs trickle). Are you aware of other useful charger chips easy to obtain more info while charging ?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon - Yes my initial circuit the TIP base is controlled by avr logic output and switch transistor. My main concern is the heat generated. Can you recommend an alternative circuit using a Mosfet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think (tentatively) that this is what you mean - but you need to play around with the schematic editor and make your own version.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fw1nRm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is intended to work by assuming a 1.2 volt base-emitter drop, leaving 0.6 volts across the .3 ohm resistor, fixing the emitter current at 2 amps.

This is a decent start, but you need to keep a few things in mind

1) The data sheet really won't tell you about how the circuit will work. Note that, from figure 1, you can assume a current gain at 2 amps of about 3000. From figure 2, you can see that Vbe at 2 amps is about 1.7 volts, which would seem to mess up your calculations. But notice that this is a *saturation* voltage, and the note at upper right says that the transistor is being run at a gain of 250, not 3000. To understand this, you need to go study what "saturation" in a transistor means.

2) Let's assume that the Vbe actually is 1.2 volts. 1.2 to 1.4 is actually the number you can expect, so be prepared to change V2 to get the current you want. The circuit will work, right? Well, sort of. Let's say you have a 1 ohm load. Then the voltage drop across the transistor will be 12 - (2 x .3) - (2 x 1.0), or 9.4 volts. The power dissipated in the transistor will be 2 x 9.4 = 18.6 watts. Unless you do a very good job of heat sinking your transistor, it will get hot and may self-destruct. But let's say you do provide an adequate heat sink, and it just gets hot. As the temperature rises, Vbe will decrease (you need to calculate how much), and the voltage across R1 will increase. This will increase the current through the transistor. It will also decrease (somewhat) the voltage across the transistor as the voltage across the two resistors, but this will not compensate entirely for the increased current. As the current increases the power dissipated in the transistor will increase. In the worst case, you will get what is called thermal runaway, as the increasing temperature causes increasing current which causes increasing temperature, etc. and it all ends in the release of the magic smoke.

3) Trying to set the current by setting the difference in two voltages is, in general, a bad idea. The problem is that you are at the mercy of both voltages. In your circuit, think about what happens if V1 starts rising, or simply if it varies due to other (not shown on the schematic) loads.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I complete forgot the heat dissipated through the Transistor and Resistor. I made a simple test and is not suitable for embedding the circuit inside a bot toy. Can you recommend alternative circuit/tips ? My main concern is to keep the current stable at 1.9 or 2.0 A to be able to fast charge NiMh cells.

Comment: Are you aware of the absolute need for temperature monitoring during fast charge of NIMH, with termination set by dT/dt? And are you aware that this monitoring means you don't need precision control of charge current?

Comment: Temperature monitor yes, 3 sensors one in one of the cells, another one for "room" temperature, and another one with the charger circuit/transistor/ic. Using differential temperatures and stopping if something is wrong (high temperature). Regarding -dV/dt, it seems more hard to detect. Regarding current precision, i had and idea that charging over 1C or higher Amps could damage the cell, if the 1C = 1.9 or 2.0A i shouldn't provide the cell a value like 2.5, right ?

Comment: What is the capacity of your cells? I would not expect that a high charge rate variation of 25% would cause problems. What will cause problems is if the cells get too hot as they approach full charge. I believe the usual cutoff limit is 2 degrees / minute. Detecting this should not be hard, and it is critical.